# Running keras LSTM models with multiple GPU (Tensorflow backend)

Tags: keras, gpu, lstm

I have a keras LSTM model and want to run it under multiple GPUs for speed improvement. But I have some ambiguities:

1- I found that to really get the great speed on GPU I should define my network using CuDNNLSTM layer and not normal LSTM layer. To use multiple GPUs, I looked at [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model) and wanted to use multi_gpu_model() function to make distributed model. However, in the sample scripts they recommend to define the model on CPU for easy weight sharing, but my CuDNNLSTM model is not deployable on CPU and LSTM model will not benefit from the enhancements provided by GPU. What is the correct approach?

2- So I tried many configurations, including:

- Group 1(using the normal (non-fast) LSTM layers): placing model on CPU and no copying to GPU; placing model on CPU and then use multi_gpu_model to create GPU copies; place model on default GPU and no copying to other GPU; placing model on default GPU and then use multi_gpu_model to create two GPU copies.
- Group2 (using CuDNNLSTM layer and therefore no possibility to place model on CPU): defining a single model (which Tensorflow places it on the default GPU); using multi_gpu_model to create two GPU copies.

In all cases, data parallelism (using multi_gpu_model) resulted in lower speed of execution. I didn't change anything else in my code and input data pipeline or batch sizes. What is wrong with me?

3- In general, should I only use CuDNN-type layers to get high speed computation with GPUs when I am programming at high level of keras API?

Comment: This is a very nice and practical question. I tried option 2 you have above. In a nutshell, you should not expect to get 2x the speed if you use 2 GPU's. There is some overhead of moving the data between the GPU's and then aggregating the result at each epoch. So, multi-GPU might make sense when the training time is more dependent on backward calculations. I ended up using single GPU as I was not getting the speed improvement for the extra cost.